# Excel VBA Code for adding duplicate in a specific column if found duplicates in another specific Column

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have to find duplicates in a specific column and if duplicates found put "Duplicate" for the duplicate records in another column.
For example, my column to look for duplicates is "F" and the numbers must be added in column "CG".
Can you please help me?

```vb
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn_C()

Dim ws As Worksheet

  'Set reference to the sheet in the workbook.
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
  ws.Activate 'not required but allows user to view sheet if warning message appears
  
'Declaring the lastRow variable as Long to store the last row value in the Column1
    Dim lastRow As Long

'matchFoundIndex is to store the match index values of the given value
    Dim matchFoundIndex As Long

'iCntr is to loop through all the records in the column 1 using For loop
    Dim iCntr As Long

'Finding the last row in the Column 1
    lastRow = Range("F99999").End(xlUp).Row

'looping through the column1
    For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
        'checking if the cell is having any item, skipping if it is blank.
        If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
            'getting match index number for the value of the cell
            matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("F1:F" & lastRow), 0)
            'if the match index is not equals to current row number, then it is a duplicate value
            If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
                'Printing the label in the column B
                Cells(iCntr, 80) = "Duplicate"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: if I may suggest, maybe you can try to use the duplicate method. For example : `set rg = range("f1:f" & lastRow)`. Then you make conditional formatting for rg `rg.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues` then put yellow color for the duplicate value : `With rg.FormatConditions(1): .DupeUnique = xlDuplicate: .Interior.Color = vbYellow: End With`. Filter the rg with yellow color : `Range("f1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=vbYellow, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor` then put the word "Duplicate" to column 80 by offsetting the visible range. (continue)

Comment: `rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Offset(0, 74).Value = "Duplicate"`. Clear the filter and the conditional formatting : `Range("F1").AutoFilter Field:=6: Cells.FormatConditions.Delete`. Please note, the code assumes that the sheet has no conditional formatting at all before it runs.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having with the code you posted?  You need to tell us what is or isn't happening when you run your code, and how that differs from what you want/expect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TimWilliams when i run the code, the column "CG" remains blank even when there are duplicates in the column "F". I wanted the word "Duplicate" to appear next to the duplicates and the first record remains empty.

Comment: What type of values are in ColF?  Strings/Numbers/Dates?  I would maybe suggest qualifying all your `Cells()`  and `Range()` calls with a specific worksheet, so (Eg) `ws.Cells(...)` would be more robust

Comment: `Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("F1:F" & lastRow), 0)` - you're taking the value from ColA and matching it against Col F ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn_C()



Dim ws As Worksheet

  'Set reference to the sheet in the workbook.
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
  ws.Activate 'not required but allows user to view sheet if warning message appears
  


'Declaring the lastRow variable as Long to store the last row value in the Column1
    Dim lastRow As Long

'matchFoundIndex is to store the match index values of the given value
    Dim matchFoundIndex As Long

'iCntr is to loop through all the records in the column 1 using For loop
    Dim iCntr As Long

'Finding the last row in the Column 1
    lastRow = Range("F99999").End(xlUp).Row

'looping through the column1
    For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
        'checking if the cell is having any item, skipping if it is blank.
        If Cells(iCntr, 6) <> "" Then
            'getting match index number for the value of the cell
            matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 6), Range("F1:F" & lastRow), 0)
            'if the match index is not equals to current row number, then it is a duplicate value
            If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
                'Printing the label in the column CF
                Cells(iCntr, 85) = "Duplicate"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you post your own answer it's useful to others coming along later if you describe how you fixed the problem.